# Bluebird - Mixing each() and all()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've just started using Bluebird and it's really great ! But i was wondering if i could do the following scenario :

I have a array of promises, and for each they return resolve(object) if everything is good. but i have to check if my object has some property to be sure everything is good, and i have to do it after the call to my promise.

And i also need to know when every call will be done. I've thought about a int that increments every time each() is called and when my int reaches promisesArray.length - 1, then it's done, but i've seen that Bluebird as a method called all() that's called when everything is done.

Is it possible to mix them ? Like do an .each() on my array to check if everything return object has that property and then do an .all() to know everything went well ?

Comment: I think you'll have to show us code for us to know what you're really talking about and what the best solution would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` to get all promises, and then return `Promise.resolve()` or `Promise.reject()` if all promises include the property that you need for success:

```
Promise.all(promisesArray).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(result) {
        // make the needed check for each result - for example: object.should.have.property('property')
    });
});
```

Comment: Well my bad, it actually doesnt work that great. I've used a console.log in the results.every() callback and it's only displayed once. I've made one of my promises intentionnaly fail and it doesn't display any error.

Comment: Maybe i should've explained more.. i'm using mocha, this is for unit testing. I'm using should.js also, so when i said that i was checking my object's properties, i'm using object.should.have.property('property'). But i'll try another way.

Comment: `Array.prototype.every` stops as soon as something fails, and then the trinary rejects. If you want to display an error do it in the `catch` block. In the `Promise.reject` instead of passing the results pass whatever the error should be. The `catch` block should handle the error, like `console.log('a promise failed')`.

Comment: In the 1st `them`, iterate the promises using `.forEach` instead of `every`, and run `object.should.have.property('property')` on every promise.

Comment: Works like a charm. Why didn't `Array.prototype.every` do the job ?

Comment: `Array.prototype.every` stops when a callback returns false, and returns false, or if all callbacks return true, it returns true. In your case, you wanted to iterate all returned promises, to check if they contain the property. So, it wasn't the right case for every. Update the question, and I'll update the answer.